# Change the default language of a node

Tags: 8, nodes

Given that I have a node in English as default language and Danish as a translation, is it possible to set the Danish translation as default language for the node?

Answer (score 6):

Of course.

I would do it this way:

1) Install of module [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel). 
Drupal7

2) go to drupal/devel/php
Of course.

Drupal8

3. in the textarea add:

> //please, change the nid of your node

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;    

$nid = 1;
$node = Node::load($nid);
$node->get('langcode')->value = 'da';
$node->save();
```

In Drupal7

```
$nid=1;
$node=node_load($nid);
$node->language='da';
node_save($node);
```

Comment: A slight variant for Drupal 8 is `$node->set('langcode', 'da');` or whatever your code is. I've used this, and it feels a little more proper.

Answer (score 1):

After some looking around, I discovered that you can change the language, as long as there are no other translations on that language.

Therefore, what you can do is

- Backup your content
- Delete the non-default translation
- Edit your node, now under "Language" you should be able to choose the other language as well
- Select the language you want and then Save

Now your node should have the other language as a default for your node and you can swap the two translations.

This solution is a bit of a hassle since you need to keep a backup for each translation in order to swap them afterwards, but at least there is no code involved.

Finally just to add that even if you try and alter the `langcode` of the node, it will not allow you to do so if there is an existing translation for that language so still you do not avoid deleting it.