# How do I programmatically change the node default language?

Tags: 8, nodes, i18n-l10n

I have a node already translated in 3 languages (*en*, *fr*, *es*) with *en* being the default language. and I want to change it to *fr*. I looked around and I found [`setDefaultLangcode()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3AsetDefaultLangcode/8.2.x) (protected).

Is there a way to programmatically change it?

Comment: Related: [Why is it not recommended to change the default language?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/226896/15055)

Comment: This post does not really answer in my case where I talk about the original language of a node and not about the default language of my website.

Comment: Ah yeah, I see. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Try with `$node->set('sdefault_langcode', 'fr');`  !

Comment: may be https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/change-the-default-language-of-a-node can help you

Comment: Thanks but not exactly my case (I even edited one of the answers)